# How can a person extend django.contrib.sites.admin so as to include a field from a model with a foreign key pointing at sites?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-contrib, django-sites

I am struggling to extend the django.contrib.sites.admin.  I am having a difficult time finding how to add a field to the sites admin page due to the fact that django.contrib.sites knows nothing of my foreign model.  Is there an easy way which I am overlooking which would allow me to add the field "derp" from the following example to the sites admin?  Do I have to extend django.contrib.sites.models safe/etc functionality to accomplish this? Thanks much.

```
class Herp(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    derp = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15)
```

Edit: I should mention that I have the admin.py file with a class extending SiteAdmin.  I understand the admin.site.unregister and admin.site.register.  I just do not know how to include a field with a foreign key relation back to django.contrib.sites.

Comment: Have you thought of inlines? You can define `HerpInlineAdmin`, add it to the `inlines` attribute on your `SiteAdmin`, then unregister `Site`, and register it again with new `SiteAdmin`. Your field then will be present on Site admin page.

Comment: @Anton: yes, that is what I wanted.  I guess I was concentrating too much on the fact I was wanting to add to a preexisting admin page I had no control over.  That combined with the fact I didn't have the model pk set up like I should which also helped.  If you want to post your answer as an answer I'll give you a check.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.inlines) would do that. You can define `HerpInlineAdmin`, add it to the `inlines` attribute on your `SiteAdmin`, then unregister `Site`, and register it again with new `SiteAdmin`.

Although this won't actually add anything to the `Site`'s admin *form*, the `derp` field will be present on Site's admin *page* as an inline.